# At with stage I need to create an object disclose to the button methods?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have this method, called (post back) by a `LinkButton` on client side, by an user:

```
protected void myOwnMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myObject.Word = "Word";
}
```

well, `myObject` must be already instantiate before, so it must be accesible here and after (at the `Page_Load` state).

In fact, instantiate it at `Page_Load` I get

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you looking for where `myObject` is instantiated?  We don't know what `myObject` is, so there's no way for us to know.

Comment: @J. Steen: I know! So which Page_ I Need to use?

Comment: @J.Steen I thought so too, but according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx control events (like button clicks) occur after page load. I haven't done heavy ASP.NET for a few years, so maybe my memory is just off.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yeah - I could have sworn clicks happen before load, but it's been a few years since I did webforms. ^^;

Comment: @J.Steen NP. I suspect something else is at play here. Perhaps markzzz isn't instantiating the object on post-back?

Comment: We can all guess at answers (and some already have below), but I just don't see enough information in the question to be of any use.  What is `myObject` and where should it be instantiated?  How is it being used?  What is its scope?  Maybe reproduce the problem with minimal code and share the entire code-behind file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object has to be recreated every postback, your best bet is to instantiate it in `Page_Init`

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myObject = new MyObject();
}
```

Note: if the dynamically created object has/uses viewstate, it *should* be restored after `Page_Init` automatically. Eg: a textbox retains it's value.

Comment: I didn't -1 you so I can't elaborate on why you were given -1 :<